# How to mute warnings on Hyperscript attributes

Tags: reactjs, htmx, hyperscript, elysiajs

I have a React component using some property of [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org), for example this snippet:

```
      <form 
        hx-post={path} 
        hx-target={target} 
        hx-swap={swap}
        _="on htmx:afterRequest reset() me"
      >
```

I permanently see this warning message on `_=`:

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; "hx-post": string; "hx-target": string; "hx-swap": string; _: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HtmlFormTag'.
  Property '_' does not exist on type 'HtmlFormTag'.ts(2322)
```

So I wish to know if there is any way to mute that warning message.

I'm using Bun, ElysiaJs, Htmx with VSCode.